# Question about real analytic function

Tags: real-analysis

I have a function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, which I know by assumption is real analytic in a neighborhood of the origin.

Therefore, I know that $$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} x^k$$ holds for $x$ in a neighborhood of zero.

Now I know for the power series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} x^k$, that its radius of convergence is infinite.

Given real analyticity and this fact, can I conclude that $$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} x^k$$ must hold true for all $x \in \mathbb R$?

I would be very grateful for answers and explanations.

Comment: Are you sure about that this  $$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} x^k$$  holds in a neighborhood of zero? If $f$ would a holomorphic function, ok, but if only real analytic??

Comment: Isn't that the definition of real analytic?

Comment: Yes, it is ok, my error,sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can't $f(x)$ just be zero for $|x|<1$ and $1$ otherwise, for a counterexample?

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. If I know that $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is infinitely many times differentiable, does this help?

Comment: No because it can be identically zero for $|x|<1$ and then just make it non-zero using bump functions. It's hopeless. For example try $f(x)=0$ for $x<=1$ and $f(x)=e^{-1/(x-1)^2}$ for $x>1$. The rapidly decreasing exponential ensures the function is infinitely differentiable at 1.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not---if one takes any nonzero real-analytic function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ whose power series at $0$ converges everywhere and the indicator function $\chi_I$ for some finite open interval containing $0$, then the power series of $\chi_I f$ at $0$ coincides with that of $f$ but $f$ and $\chi_I f$ are different functions. (If they were the same, $f$ would be identically zero on some open interval and, since it is real-analytic, it would be identically zero, a contradiction.)

One can produce smooth counterexamples at the cost of a little simplicity by replacing $\chi_I$ with some smooth [bump function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function) that is identically $1$ on some open neighborhood of $0$.